# libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r, linux

I'm trying to run R on a local linux server. R version 4.0.4 was installed using conda. I can see the package (or that something called R is in the correct location). However, I receive the following error when trying to run R:

> error while loading shared libraries:
> libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168787/libreadline-so-6-issue-in-ubuntu-18-04) post in [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Before I try and answer what's the result of `uname -a`?

It seems like you might not have  `libreadline-dev` installed

Should be fixed with simple (assuming you are on a debian based distro)

```
sudo apt install  libreadline-dev
```